# An identity about a continuous local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $M_t$ be a continuous local martingale with $M_0=0$ and define $I_t^0=1$ and $I_t^n= \int_0^t I_s^{n-1}\; dM_s$. Prove that we have
$$n I_t^n= I_t^{n-1}- \int_0^t I_s^{n-2} \;d((M)_t) $$
where $(M)_t$ is the quadratic variation of $M$.

Comment: integration by parts should work.

Comment: There is a problem with your statement. If you compute the case $n=2$ (with integration by parts), you obtain $2I^2 = (I^1)^2- \int I^0 d(M)$, which is different from your formula.

Comment: @phil Could you tell us where you found this formula?